# Web Server configuration

Tags: unix, web, lamp, server, debian-based

I'm learning for myself how to set up a web server using lamp. I want to be able to browse file from a browser such as chrome, midori or whatever. I'd like to have differents spaces for each user too.

For now, I have my server on 192.168.x.x 
If I search for this address I reach the main page with the "It works!" from apache2. And I installed webmin so https://192.168.x.x:10000 works too and I can use the webmin interface.

For now, I can ssh on my server with root and my users.

Now I'm a bit lost and I don't really now what to do for the next steps :

be able to do something like www.myserver.foo/user1 and reach the "tree" for the actual user
but I don't understand how to "alias" www.myserver.foo to my server address ._.

Thanks for any help

Oh yes, I'm running bodhi x32 on vmware player (ubuntu based)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to add sub domains, so each user have it's space, database? From webmin you can great separate VM . Also you can have a domain for free and point it to your server.